# yii framework main.php use variable of other array in params

Tags: arrays, yii, parameters

I want to do the following:
Create an array inside the main.php params section that uses a value of another array inside that params section.
How can i do that?

Tried something like this:

```
'params'=>array(

    //service types constants
    'service_types'=>array(
    'st_defect'=>1,
    'st_retour'=>2,
    'st_order'=>3,
    ),

//open times of department 0=monday
    'st_open'=>array(
    **service_types['st_retour']**=>array(
                              0=>array(800,1700),   
                              1=>array(800,1700),   
                              2=>array(800,1700),   
                              3=>array(800,1700),
                              4=>array(800,1700),
            ),  
        ),

), //end params array
```

The part between ** needs to point to the previous declared array.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the configuration of main.php in this:

```
$ret = array();
$ret['params'] =array();

    //service types constants
    $ret['params']['service_types']=array(
    'st_defect'=>1,
    'st_retour'=>2,
    'st_order'=>3,
    );

//open times of department 0=monday
    $ret['params']['st_open']=array(
                             $ret['params']['service_types']['st_retour']=array(
                              0=>array(800,1700),   
                              1=>array(800,1700),   
                              2=>array(800,1700),   
                              3=>array(800,1700),
                              4=>array(800,1700),
            );  
        );


return $ret;
```

That way i can use the previous declared array inside the next and i keep settings together for a readable format. So settings for one page are clustered.

Thanx for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can move `services_type` to a variable and use it in two places:

```
$service_types = array(
'st_defect'=>1,
'st_retour'=>2,
'st_order'=>3,
);

return array(     /*** .... ****/

'params'=>array(

    //service types constants
    'service_types'=>$services_types,

//open times of department 0=monday
    'st_open'=>array(
    $service_types['st_retour']=>array(
                              0=>array(800,1700),   
                              1=>array(800,1700),   
                              2=>array(800,1700),   
                              3=>array(800,1700),
                              4=>array(800,1700),
            ),  
        ),

), //end params array

....
```

Remember that the config file is just PHP; you can use variables, functions, includes, etc.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that i have a main.php for general config and a client_main.php for client specific settings. Client_main overwrites main.php I also have a lot of settings, this will divides stuff that belongs together. I would like to keep it near each other so it's more readable/easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the declaration of that array outside the `params` array declaration:

```
$service_types = array(
    'st_defect'=>1,
    'st_retour'=>2,
    'st_order'=>3,
);
```

And then

```
'params'=>array(
    'service_types'=> $service_types
    'st_open'=>array(
        $service_types['st_retour'] => array(...)
    ),
)
```